# ComboBox change depending on type of cell

Tags: c#, combobox

What I want is that this function will fill the `comboboxPromoter` by using information from a data grid view which is in another form.

Basically it should work like this:
If event type is clubber, then display all promoter (names) which their eventType is (clubbing) into the combo box. else If event type is exhibitor display all promoters (names) related to exhibitions.

The code below is the one into the combo box:

```
private void cmbPromoter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        promoterForm frm = new promoterForm();

        PromoterBL pBL = new PromoterBL();

        if (txtType.Text == "Exhibition")
        {
        cmbPromoter.DataSource = pBL.GetPromotersByType(frm.dgvPromoters.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        cmbPromoter.Refresh();
        }
        else if (txtType.Text == "Clubbing")
        {
         cmbPromoter.DataSource = pBL.GetPromotersByType(frm.dgvPromoters.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
         cmbPromoter.Refresh();
        }
```

And this is the class of promoter

```
 public List<Advertiser> GetPromotersByType(string pType)
    {

        EventTicketEntities database = new EventTicketEntities(); //ALWAYS 
        return database.Advertisers.Where(p => p.PromoterType.Contains(pType)).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try DataTemplateSelector, it's fairly simple to use:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47923/Using-a-different-DataTemple-when-a-WPF-ComboBox-i